# I can't get the REST service response in Angular

Tags: rest, angular, cors

Inside our company's VPN I can call the web service (which is a REST service) fine, on FF and Chrome. I need to connect to it from Angular 2 though. Now, I tried to call the REST service(which is inside VPN) from Angular 2,  in several ways, and I am always getting the message about CORS("No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401." in Chrome and "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://webwassvc-test.servizi.gr-u.it/essigEAIM/rest/monitoring/integrations/all?pag=1. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)." in Firefox). I tried setting the about:config:security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false, and it didn't help. The sysadmin on the REST server end told me he opened the server for CORS (cross domain) calls, so I think the problem is on my end, but I don't know what can it be. Any advice, please?

UPDATE: I can access the REST service and get the data from it, through PHP as middleware (localhost/angular2_site/file.php), but not from angular directly (localhost:4200).

Comment: Try to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header of the request

Comment: You need to have a Content Security Policy meta tag on your http page, and you need to set an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.  Do you have both of these?

Comment: In your REST api, response header should have
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200

Comment: It sounds like the sysadmin of the REST server is mistaken. If that server were actually opened for CORS calls it would be sending an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` respond header. But it’s not sending that header. There is no way you can work around that on the client side from your JavaScript code.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have my website in localhost. I can access and get the REST service data (which is on another server) from localhost/angular2_site/file.php , but not from Angular (localhost:4200). Is this normal?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic It’s not normal but I guess it depends on exactly how the REST server is configured. It might have `http://localhost` safelisted in some way but not `http://localhost:4200`. Or it’s imaginable that it might be configured to not send the  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header to non-port-80 origins (dunno why anybody would ever configure something that way but who knows).

Answer (score 1):

Another option it's to manage it with a proxy or load balancer.

If you are developing with anuglar-cli you can use the [Proxy To Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#proxy-to-backend) support of the angular-cli. `--proxy-config`

from the angular-cli readme:

> Say we have a **api server** running on http://localhost:3000/api and we want
>   all calls to http://localhost:4200/api to go to that server.
>
> We create a file next to projects package.json called proxy.conf.json
>   with the content
>
> ```
> {
>   "/api": {
>     "target": "http://localhost:3000",
>     "secure": false
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You can read more about what options are available here
>   webpack-dev-server proxy settings
>
> and then we edit the package.json file's start script to be
>
> "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json", now run it with
>   npm start

So at the end you can call your services as:

```
getUsers() : Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('/api/users').map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have a REST server on another port, and my angular is running on 4200. I need data from that server available to Angular (Angular is running on port 4200), not the other way around.

Comment: in the angular-cli example the angular server it's running at port 4200 and the server service it's running at 3000. What port it's running yours?

Comment: Angular is as usual, on port 4200. The web server, however, from which I want to get the data is on web somewhere, and I can get the data from it using PHP (as stated in the question).